# ruby date scope not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, time

I have a date scope set in a model that presents guide information if it is within a current date range.
For example:

A guide entry is set between the 10th of June and the 18th of July, therefore this code should activate the scope.

```
   scope :active_at_date, lambda { where("date_starting < :date and date_ending > :date", date: Date.today )}
```

It seems to be working fine locally. However on Heroku it does not.

Why? and how can I fix it so that it works on Heroku?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work on Heroku? Can you post the output of `Model.active_at_date` when you run it in the heroku rails console?

Comment: Once live - or deployed - the code doesn't work as it does locally... I ran the console and got this - 

irb(main):001:0> Guide.active_at_date
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: Can you verify that in your heroku database you have at least one guide with a starting date before today and an end date after today?

Comment: ok, so I checked, and if I specify that the date starts before today and ends after today, it displays appropriately. However, if i specify that the date starts today, it does not display.

Here is an entry that I would like to behave as described...
irb(main):001:0> Guide.last
=> #<Guide id: 1, date_starting: "2014-06-18 00:00:00", date_ending: "2014-06-22 00:00:00", image_file_name: "dove_small.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 22302, image_updated_at: "2014-06-18 19:10:32", title: "Simon Manfield - Memoria Histórica ", description: "....

Comment: Since today is June 18th, wouldn't that not actually fall within the range you specified? June 18th can't be less than itself. See what happens when you change `date_starting` to "2014-06-17" for that record or change the `date_starting` comparator from `<` to `<=`  . You could also try to find another record for which today actually falls within the range.